# jQuery.inArray() not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

I need to check if a number is present in an array of number that I get from PHP, and if yes render a data coming from iosocket. But for some reason this code won't work.
The array return 20, 25 and the number to check is 20 f.example

```
<script>
var negozi_seguiti = <?php echo json_encode($negozi_seguiti); ?>;
var post = io('http://1clickfashion.com:3002');
post.on("test-channel:App\\Events\\Post", function(message){
  // increase the power everytime we load test route 
  alert(negozi_seguiti);
  if (jQuery.inArray(negozi_seguiti, message.data.negozio) == -1) {
    $('#timeline').addClass("timeline");
    $('#timeline').prepend(message.data.timeline);
    $('#rocket').hide();
  }
});
</script>
```

What i'm wrong?

Comment: [`jQuery.inArray( value, array [, fromIndex ] )`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) you seem to be passing arguments in the wrong order

Comment: Not related, but make it a habit to use `===` instead of `==`

Answer (score 3):

You misused [`inArray`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/), you inverted arguments, use it like this :

```js
var arr = [20, 21];

console.log($.inArray(20, arr))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

I also suggest you tu use [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) which works the same way but is called directly on the array reducing the risk of doing a mistake like this :

```js
var arr = [20, 21];

console.log(arr.indexOf(20));
```

It makes your code clearer, you get rid of jQuery, and finally it is [faster](https://jsperf.com/in-array-vs-inarray-vs-indexof).

Comment: unfortunately not work arry is output array:2 [▼
  0 => 25
  1 => 20
]

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting proper value in your array `negozi_seguiti` variable then you need to change `$.inArray('search_value', 'yourarray')` like bellow.

```js
var negozi_seguiti = <?php echo json_encode($negozi_seguiti); ?>;
var post = io('http://1clickfashion.com:3002');
post.on("test-channel:App\\Events\\Post", function(message) {
  // increase the power everytime we load test route 
  alert(negozi_seguiti);
  if (jQuery.inArray(message.data.negozio, negozi_seguiti) == -1) {
    $('#timeline').addClass("timeline");
    $('#timeline').prepend(message.data.timeline);
    $('#rocket').hide();
  }
});
```